"xrandr --addmode" is refusing to work
I'm trying to create a custom resolution that mimics my iPad so I can mirror my desktop to my iPad via Weylus without a stretched or cropped display, but I keep running into an issue. Trying to use xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2160x1620_60.00 The mode I created) results in this response:
 Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
 Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
 Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
 Serial number of failed request:  41
 Current serial number in output stream:  42

For reference, I'm using an Nvidia card with Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 + KDE plasma 5.27.11 so I'm not sure if this is just another Nvidia-exclusive problem.
I've tried it several times and I'm 100% positive I'm entering in all the command properties so I am very lost.
I have noticed I can set a resolution by typing it out in the advanced section of the Nvidia X server settings program, but I'd like to have it as a resolution option I can easily and quickly access via my system settings. it's also stretched rather than pillar box the way I want it via this method.
I am on Ubuntu 22.04

To be clear you are not running any version of Ubuntu?

@DavidDE my apologies. i am on Ubuntu 22.04

--addmode is usually one of a series of commands, the first usually being cvt to generate a modeline, then --newmode to using the modeline, but you have not listed those commands or the success/failure/messages resulting in those commands. And confirm you are using x11 and not Wayland echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
